# Why can't I write sematicLabel in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am quite a beginner at Flutter so I have  a question why can't I fit sematicLabel in here?

[image: Code]

Comment: There’s no property named sematicLabel that container has!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) doesn't have a property called `semanticLabel`. You can use instead [Semantics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html).

```
Semantics(
  label: 'Venus',
  child: Container(
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/venus.png'),
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  ),
)
```